# populating data from userform checkboxes & optional buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a userform that I want to be able to populate values in a data tab as well as default to certain values.
I think I have text boxes and combo boxes down, but cannot find info on using multiple optional buttons to generate data to one cell depending on the selection.[image: example draft]

from the example, my criteria would be "secondary insurance" how do I go about linking them all so that, lets say cell b1 is populated with the selected option? 
I'm completely guessing but I think checkboxes are a little more simple, true if checked and false if unchecked.
What I have so far is just a code I came across to fill in a cell with the value of the designated text/combo box and was just going to repeat for each column I need to set a criteria for.

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row
    ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text 'Adds the TextBox1 into Col A & Last Blank Row
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

combobox list

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.Value = ("N/A")
ComboBox1.List = Split("N/A Yes No")
End Sub
```

Please let me know if I lack information and or how to attach my test worksheet, hopefully you can see the picture (I can't on my work server).
Thanks in advance for any and all education.

Comment: have you checked [THIS](http://www.homeandlearn.org/code_for_vba_option_buttons.html)? To me it is not clear what you want, but that may help you a lot to get a start if that is what you are looking for...

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of that for what I want but I think it's entirely different. Basically I want to fill out this userform with the given options and have it populate my selections in a data tab.
 So for the 3 option buttons I want a single cell for the column "secondary Insurance" to be filled in depending on the chosen selection N/A, Yes or No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the caption of the option button is the same as you want as cell text, then something like this may be what you want to store it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim LastRow As Range
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set LastRow = .Rows(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Cells
    If OptionButton1 Then
      LastRow(2).Value2 = Me.OptionButton1.Caption
    ElseIf Me.OptionButton2 Then
      LastRow(2).Value2 = Me.OptionButton2.Caption
    Else
      LastRow(2).Value2 = Me.OptionButton3.Caption
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

This will set the desired cell to the value of the caption of the option button you have selected.

To load the data back in the userform, you could use something like this:

```
Sub Load_in(Row_To_Load As Long)
  Dim MyRow As Range
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set MyRow = .Rows(Row_To_Load).Cells
    If MyRow(2).Value2 = OptionButton1.Caption Then
      OptionButton1.Value = True
    ElseIf MyRow(2).Value2 = OptionButton2.Caption Then
      OptionButton2.Value = True
    Else
      OptionButton3.Value = True
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

For this, I assumed that the names hasn't been changed. Also if nothing is selected, the third option (N/A) will be used. The same goes for loading it back. If you do not want that, simply change the `Else` part to `ElseIf` so it looks like the first 2 options.

Comment: Is the use of find last row in your example a better or more efficient way to use it than mine?
I did manage to get it to populate using something along the same lines of "if option button 1 = true then return X value in cell B"

Comment: I probably got you wrong... Because, it should do what you are looking for... if the button is pressed, then it writes in the cell in B the caption of the option button... still, you also could use `LastRow(2).Value2 = "Yes"` for the first button (and "No" for the second / "N/A" for the `Else`)... for getting it back, you would use `If MyRow(2).Value2 = "Yes" Then` for the first ("No" for the second)... Oh and the way of setting the active line... this only depends on *"what you like"* (as long as time doesn't matter)

Comment: Got it working however,  is there are way to auto populate additional cells with N/A based off this selection? for example, If these 3 buttons are of a main category for cell A which leads into additional selections for cells B & C, they would also be "N/A". Can I do this without having to make a "N/A" selection for each one? I was not able to add additional cells/columns to my code as I thought I would. `ws.Range ("B,C" & LastRow.Value = "N/A"`

Comment: if you only want the N/A if N/A is selected, then simply change the `Else` to  `ElseIf Me.OptionButton3 Then`... if you leave it as it is, then it automatically should pop N/A if nothing is selected... and for column C: I don't know what you are doing for real or how to evaluate what to put in there, but in theory it should be possible...

Comment: I was looking for a way to list the range of the cells that I want affected by selecting the N/A option but I think that may be slightly off topic.    I got it to work by listing each cell separately after my if true statement. Thanks for the replies will mark.